# Is it possible to share a link to a specific folder / directory in a public GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I know that one can get a permanent link to a specific *file* on a public GitHub repository (as explained [here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/using-files/getting-permanent-links-to-files)).

However, is it possible to get a permanent link to a specific directory? Specifically, I want to share a permanent link to the following directory (`power_analysis`) in the following public GitHub repository: https://github.com/Social-Body-Lab/stress_adaptation_and_motor_memory/tree/main/power_analysis

My understanding is that this could change depending on future commits, but I want a permanent link to this folder / directory that I can share in a study pre-registration (which cannot be changed after publication).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How would it change based on future commits?

Comment: No, your URL doesn't have any relation with "commits under this path" and will not change (contrary to @lee answer's URL) even after extending history

Comment: Sorry, I was reading the page I linked to and came across the following, which made me think the link might change: "The version of a file at the head of branch can change as new commits are made, so if you were to copy the normal URL, the file contents might not be the same when someone looks at it later." I understand it is a file, but thought it might be the same for directories. Also, why the downvote? I mean its not the greatest question, but it wasn't like I didn't look into it first (I am just learning to use GitHub)?

Comment: But thank you @LazyBadger for the explanation. I think that makes sense. So the URL of the GitHub link that I shared will never change as long as I keep the directory on the repository?

Comment: Yes, it will be always the "latest state of"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When viewing the Github UI, you can use the ['y' shortcut to link to a specific version](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/using-files/getting-permanent-links-to-files). Doing this for the tree in your question results in https://github.com/Social-Body-Lab/stress_adaptation_and_motor_memory/tree/2cb95b7c1651a35ec3ff44d50df8bdc1db282aeb/power_analysis which links to the tree associated with the current commit at the head of the `master` branch.

Comment: Hash of commit (`2cb95...`) in **permanent** URL is The Bad Idea (tm)